# How to set timeout settings for each Promise?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

In Scala we have something like:

```
Future.firstCompletedOf(Seq(
   normalFuture,
   Promise.timeout(doSth(), timeout)
))
```

And this will return a Promise and it's non-blocking.

However in Java I cannot find such thing, I can use promise.get(timeout) but that is a blocking method.

Any helps?

Comment: I think your talking about Threads, but I havent ever used Scala so I cant be sure, look at http://www.quepublishing.com/articles/article.aspx?p=26044 for a basic example.

Comment: @ns47731 You are talking about general java programming but in Play they have some mechanisms to simplify that.

Comment: It sounds like `ExecutorService#submit` is what you're looking for.